# Retrieving a file from a Tomcat Server on an Apache box

Tags: java, regex, apache, jsp, tomcat

So I am working on a web application with JSP on Tomcat 7. I need to be able to retrieve a log file from a few Tomcat servers saved as shared folder drives on my computer and then be able to parse it with a regex expression. However, is there anyway to retrieve the file without having to manually upload it with a form.

I tried this

```
public void init() throws ServletException {

        // Define base path somehow. You can define it as init-param of the servlet.
        this.filePath = "/Users/oakesjo/Documents/LogViewerTools";

        // In a Windows environment with the Application server running on the
        // c: volume, the above path is exactly the same as "c:\files".
        // In UNIX, it is just straightforward "/files".
    }

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {

        // Get requested file by path info.
        String requestedFile = request.getPathInfo();
...}
```

However, the `this.filePath` will only let me access files on my C: drive (local computer) instead of other  network drives. Is there any other way to configure this?  Also: Does there exist an option of just automatically storing the file to a string?

Answer (score 0):

Your applet might not have rights to where the log file is saved. When you use windows, make sure you have full acces to the folder you are trying to access. Once you got your file, you can read it via bufferedReader and make the reader put all the contents into a String.